# Certbot Nginx/Ubuntu16.04 timeout

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, timeout, ubuntu-16.04, certbot

After successfully configuring nginx on my EC2 server/Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 I tried to install certbot several times but failed every time by having a timeout issue.

I followed the procedure at https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-nginx
I get a success message, but when I go to test : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mysite.com

It doesn't work. 
Also if I try: curl -I https://54.238.241.234:443 # it fails
However: curl -I http://54.238.241.234:80 # works

My Nginx config is the following:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;


        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mysite.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                    allow all;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0002/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com-0002/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

My UFW status is the following

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

My route53 config is correct too.

I really wonder where does this problem come from, and would appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks in advance.